# Android Hierarchical/nested checkboxes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, user-controls, material-design

I need to implement [this](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1zn-VtNelawmXvBepVlv2hRmB6Egf6Roc%2Fselectioncontrols-checkboxes-usage-parentchild-1c.png) (Material checkboxes) type of activity, with dynamic tree layout.
Sorry but I'm little newbie on Android platform, so please explain to me what I need to get an activity like this from scratch.

Thanks in advance.

Bye

EDIT: Fixed URL that now point to correct image.

Answer (score 0):

You must be more specific...

But if all what you want e implement a checkbox, you'll need:

1. XML layout with the widgets
2. Activity to handle events and values from the widgets

You could get a [simple tutorial](https://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/android-checkbox-example.html) easily seaching the web..

Comment: thanks Giovanne, sorry for the poor question. I'll try to be moore specific.
Your answer is a good starting point, but my need is to have a hierarchical (more than one level) list of checkboxes. What I don't know, is if can be done without using third-party libs.
This is why I'm looking for a simple code example.

Cheers :)

Comment: What do you mean by **hierarchical**? Do they have some kind of dependency? Can you give an example? Maybe a pic...

Comment: Ok, I'll try. You have a street with one or more building, every building have one or more stair.
User must be able to select one or mode stairs in the same hierarchical list.
I need to represent this model with UX proposed by Material's usability guidelines (like the screenshot I've mentioned before).

Thanks in advance